# Changing paragraph by clicking on list

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I asked this question yesterday!:

> I'm just learning the html, css, javascript stuff and I stuck on a point. I have a webpage,designed by css.

How to click on the list item to change the PARAGRAPH only,but not the css designed (see picture)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zs59U.jpg]

the list is in:

```
<div id="bodyleft">
<h2>History</h2>
<li><a href="#">1996-2000</a></li>
the paragraph is:

<div id="bodyright">
<h2>blah blah blah blah blah blah </h2>
<p> blah blah blah....  </p> and I want thange THIS!!
```

**I've got a useful answer:**

```
var ul = document.querySelector('#bodyleft ul');
ul.onclick = function(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var p = document.querySelector('#bodyright p');
    p.innerHTML = 'Clicked on ' + target.innerHTML;
    return false;
};
```

**But** every `<li>` item doing the **same**. How can I **separate** them like:
click on `<li>Item1</li> ->Write1`
click on `<li>Item2</li> ->Write2`
click on `<li>Item3</li> ->Write3`??

Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/NwFXE/

OK THAT WAS THAT I WANT :=> http://jsfiddle.net/NwFXE/5/

Thanks for helping!

Comment: See my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this solution:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeMe(id){
            var test = document.getElementById('main')
            if (id == 'item1') {
                test.innerHTML = 'item1 clicked';
            }
            else if (id == 'item1') {
                test.innerHTML = 'item1 clicked';
            }
            else if (id == 'item2') {
                test.innerHTML = 'item2 clicked';
            }
            else if (id == 'item3') {
                test.innerHTML = 'item3 clicked';
            }
            else if (id == 'item4') {
                test.innerHTML = 'item4 clicked';
            }
            else if (id == 'item5') {
                test.innerHTML = 'item5 clicked';
            }       
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bodyleft">
<h2>History</h2>
<li id="item1" onclick="changeMe('item1');"><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
<li id="item2" onclick="changeMe('item2');"><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
<li id="item3" onclick="changeMe('item3');"><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
<li id="item4" onclick="changeMe('item4');"><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
<li id="item5" onclick="changeMe('item5');"><a href="#">Item5</a></li>

the paragraph is:

<div id="bodyright">
<h2>blah blah blah blah blah blah </h2>
<p id="main"> this will change  </p> 
and I want thange THIS!!

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are targeting UL.

Instead change it to LI as below :

```
var li = document.querySelector('#bodyleft ul li');
    li.onclick = function(e){
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var target = evt.target || evt.srcElement;
    var p = document.querySelector('#bodyright p');
    p.innerHTML = 'Clicked on ' + target.innerHTML;
    return false;
};
```

Comment: I've tried this but in this case only first item of the list working,others do nothing.

Comment: @PeterBarta - You should make a jsfiddle replicating the problem.

Comment: try using index of the same in that case.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` returns the first match in the list, so the `ul li` is returning the first `li`. Only target the `ul`, and you should be fine:

```
var li = document.querySelector('#bodyleft ul');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/NwFXE/4/

Comment: And how can I make that ,clicking on the list items write different texts? Because in this case every <li> item write the same

Comment: Not for me...every item displays the correct text... running Chrome -- @PeterBarta

Comment: I mean its write 'Clicked on ' + target.innerHTML, but I want write different texts on every click like : List1->Hello List2->Bye List3->Welcome